# Hilbert scheme of curves in weighted projective spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I am trying to learn about Hilbert scheme of curves in a weighted protective space.

In my next step I am interested in Hilbert scheme of curves in a complete intersection in a weighted protective space.

Can any one please provide me with a reference on these topics. Also can any one give me a brief review about these topics.

Comment: What kind of curves are you studying?  Even for curves in $\mathbb{P}^3$, there are many open questions.

Comment: Jason Starr: I am interested in conics.

Comment: In that case, I recommend the preprint of Cristian Minoccheri.

Comment: Jason Starr: I am sorry can you be more specific. Thanks.

Comment: "... can you be more specific." There is only one preprint of Cristian Minoccheri.

Comment: Jason Starr: Thanks, I got it. I will read it thoroughly. Is there anything else which is more explicit than this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47820/discussion-between-sag1-and-jason-starr).